# Copy file from device to a local folder

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

im using `string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);`
to get dragged files into my app and copy them to a diffrent location

It appears that my app is recognizing any droped item except for those originated on a device(cameras/smartphones etc)

how can i solve this and get the path for the dropped items to later use with

```
FileSystem.CopyDirectory
```

here is a short version of my code

```
private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            FileInfo fileInfo;
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                   fileInfo=new FileInfo(file);
                   FileSystem.CopyDirectory(fileInfo.FullName, target, UIOption.AllDialogs);
                }
        }
```

on debug i can see that "files" is null.
again , this works perfectly from all other window explorer drag and drops

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your device is a Windows Mobile 6 using ActiveSync or similar, the device's files appear in the shell namespace, but they are not a part of the filing system. Therefore, they cannot be copied using normal filing system copy APIs.

The dragged items can be accessed by getting the Shell Id List using:

```
e.Data.GetData("Shell IDList Array") as System.IO.MemoryStream
```

These can be translated in to a path using the methods in the [SHGetPathFromIDList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for normal file paths, I'm not sure if this will work for device paths.

Finally, the [CeReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917409.aspx) and related functions will be needed to read the file from the device in order to copy it.

Even if this all works for a Windows Mobile device, it is no guarantee that some other kind of device will work this way. I'm afraid that this is likely to be difficult to implement, I hope this information is useful to get you going.

Comment: hi there and thanks, im trying to copy files from a camera/mobile phone by dragging and dropping items to the app so it is now windows mobile... do you have an idea on how to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Similar advice applies. The shell namespace contains objects which may, or may not be files in the filing system. Your code handles the case where the objects are in the filing system, but other objects require different handling. In my answer the same steps should be used apart from CeReadFile. There should be an equivalent API for fetching files for the devices that you are supporting. In the case of cameras, this may be the Windows Imaging API. It's not something I can be of much help with, though.